# NASM range macro with accumulator

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'd like to invoke a macro N times, each time using the accumulator, ie;

```
%macro foo 1
range 1, 8, {some_partially_applied_macro %1}
%endmacro
```

is equivalent to

```
%macro foo 1
some_partially_applied_macro %1, 1
some_partially_applied_macro %1, 2
some_partially_applied_macro %1, 3
...
some_partially_applied_macro %1, 8
%endmacro
```

I tried writing the following (and several variations thereof):

```
%macro range 3
%assign i %1
%rep %2
%[%3 i]
%assign i i+1
%endrep
%endmacro
```

I've had no success.

An important thing to note is the 3rd argument may need to be partially applied.

Comment: I don't understand what you intend to do. What's `%[%3 i]` expand to? Can you edit your question to make the intended output clearer?

Comment: The inner part of the second macro (`foo 1`) is what I want range to expand to given the input just above.

Comment: I'm sorry, kvanberendonck, I still don't get it. I'm not a very sophisticated macro user. Do I understand that the third parameter to "range" is the name of the "partially applied"(?) macro? Is your variable "i" what you're calling "the accumulator"? When you say "partially applied", do you mean to invoke the "inner macro" a variable (%2) number of times? Each time with a first parameter same as the first parameter to "range" and a second parameter of "i"?

Comment: Partially applied is a functional term, sorry. But, to make it really simple, I'd like the third parameter to `range` to just be splatted before the accumulator. The reason for this is I may want to specify the first 2 arguments of another macro ("partially applied") and then have the accumulator as the third.

Comment: So if the third argument was `foo bar 3` I'd like it to output `foo bar 3 1`, `foo bar 3 2` ... `foo bar 3 N`.

Comment: I just copied your proposed macro, fed it a couple of test instances, and assembled it with `nasm -e` (preprocess only) and I'm getting the output you describe. How is it not working for you? You might want to ask this on the Nasm Forum - better macro users there.

Comment: See here for the output I get: https://gist.github.com/kvanberendonck/9458222 . `vmi_op_add_r` remains unexpanded.

Comment: Sorry kvanberendonck I'm lost. Wish I could help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. Remove the `%[...]` part around `%[%3 i]`.

It was tricking me because I was testing it like so:

```
range 1, 8, {some_partially_applied_macro %1}
```

Actually has to have a comma at the end after `%1`, or NASM doesn't expand it properly (it doesn't see it as a proper comma separated macro).

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Can you post a more completed example?