# How to pass a block of code in nasm macro assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, nasm

I would like to pass a block of code in a for loop with my macro:

```
%macro for 3+
    %%beginLoop:
        mov ecx, %1
    %%Loop:
        cmp ecx, %2
        je %%exit
        push ecx

        %3

        pop ecx
        inc ecx
        jmp %%Loop
    %%exit:
%endmacro
```

Is there any way of doing something like:

```
for 0, 10, %{
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, fooBar
  mov edx, 10
  int 0x80
}
```

?

Comment: You're looking for `%rep 10` / `%endrep`.  https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.7 .  If you want to do something more complicated around each block, that might not be possible: [NASM macros with "multi-line arguments"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52391602) is unanswered.

Comment: You might have to make your "loop body" a macro and pass that macro to another for it to expand, which I think might be what [NASM range macro with accumulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22262308) is doing.